# join two tables in sql using common column

Tags: sql

I have two table.

`tablea` contains assetID, branchID, latID, lonID. Each row is unique.

```
assetID, branchID, latID, lonID
```

For every `assetID` in `tablea`, there are 32 entries in `tableb` in the following format:

```
assetID, branchID, risk1, risk2, risk3, risk4
```

I want to randomly select 10 rows from `tablea`, pull the data from `tableb` for these random `assetID` and join them together to get the table in following format

```
assetID, branchID, latID, lonID, risk1, risk2, risk3, risk4
```

So far I have the below sql query but I am unable to join the two tables:

```
select * from tableb where branchID <2 and assetID in
(select top 10 assetID from tablea where assetID is not null and branchID <2)
```

Comment: Firstly, do not use branchID conditon in the outer query, it seems unnecessary assuming that both tables have the same combination of assetID and branchID. Secondly, What is the error/problem that you are facing?

Comment: Which SQL server are you using (as the details will vary: TOP vs LIMIT etc)?

Comment: Try to specify the DBMS that you are using because syntax may change

Answer (score 1):

Does this solve your problem?

```
select * from (
   select * from  /*i get the first 10 rows from tablea*/
       tablea
   where  branchID < 2
   limit 10
) as tablea
join tableb /*i pull the relative data from tableb */
on tablea.assetID = tableb.assetID and tableb.branchID < 2
```

Comment: Use limit or top in base of your DBMS ;)